# What am I doing wrong when making this shortcut?

Tags: macos, qt, shortcut, qaction, qt5.7

I'm using QT and I have a QAction, which I want to use Cmd and Plus as a shortcut to zoom in. I've found out that QKeySequence::ZoomIn will map to that, and other native key combinations for zooming in on other types of keyboards. I've used the code below to do this, however, this doesn't work correctly as I would have hoped.

```
QAction *zoomInAction = new QAction(QIcon("zoominimg.png"),"Zoom in", this);
zoomInAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence::ZoomIn);
connect(zoomInAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(zoomIn()));
```

The shortcut works when using the + key on the numpad of an external keyboard, however, when using the + key which you have to press shift then = keys to use, the shortcut no longer works, and the zoomIn method never gets called.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue before, and know how it can be solved?

I'm using Qt 5.7 on MacOS 10.12 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you experience is by design. Qt only uses [standard shortcuts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum) in order to avoid any dis-ambiguities that may happen when different keyboard layouts are used.

[An example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#keyboard-layout-issues) provided at Qt docs summarizes your problem:

> For example, the shortcuts, Ctrl plus and Ctrl minus, are often used as shortcuts for zoom operations in graphics applications, and these may be specified as "Ctrl++" and "Ctrl+-" respectively. However, the way these shortcuts are specified and interpreted depends on the keyboard layout. Users of Norwegian keyboards will note that the + and - keys are not adjacent on the keyboard, but will still be able to activate both shortcuts without needing to press the Shift key. However, users with British keyboards will need to hold down the Shift key to enter the + symbol, making the shortcut effectively the same as "Ctrl+Shift+=".
>
> Although some developers might resort to fully specifying all the modifiers they use on their keyboards to activate a shortcut, this will also result in unexpected behavior for users of different keyboard layouts.
>
> For example, a developer using a British keyboard may decide to specify "Ctrl+Shift+=" as the key sequence in order to create a shortcut that coincidentally behaves in the same way as Ctrl plus. However, the = key needs to be accessed using the Shift key on Norwegian keyboard, making the required shortcut effectively Ctrl Shift Shift = (an impossible key combination).

Therefore, if you still want to use the shortcut that involves the `Shift` modifier, you must code it yourself in addition to the default one. By doing so, you should keep in mind that your hard-coded shortcut might not work as expected on other keyboard layouts.